# Why does Google PageSpeed tell me jQuery is render blocking when it's loaded last?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using wordpress to load core jQuery with this function:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '1.10.2', true );
```

I understand the "true" statement makes the script load after the page is setup.

Google is telling me that it's still render blocking, so I've looked at alternatives which say to to place some code at the bottom of my document.

Then what is the point of registering/deregistering jquery if I have to add jquery a completely different way to stop it from render blocking?

Is there a wordpress option I can add to my code to stop this?

If it's only the jQuery code doing it should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_register_script` adds scripts to the `<head>` by default.

Specify `$in_footer` as `true`.

Docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Answer (score 0):

Those commands add jquery to the web page created by wordpress. Having gone through this process you are on I think using a cdn is probably the best I can do and not worry about google pagespeed's complaint here.